# Angular 2 Material How to Set A field Untouched

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I use Material for a form and after i post the data, i reset all input fields with `form.reset()` function in the ts file. This function clear all input fields, but then all input fields become red, because they are all touched and empty.

How can i make them untouched in the ts file? Here is the html code:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [formControl]="environment" placeholder="Environment">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let environment of environments" [value]="environment">
            {{ environment }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="environment.hasError('required')">
        * Environment is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here is the ts code:

```
this.http
    .post(url, form.value.item, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    })
    .subscribe(data => {
            form.reset();
        },
        err => {
            console.log(err);
        }
    );
```

Comment: form.reset will make the field untouched

Comment: It does an ordinary input field, but not material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an known **[issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4190)**. One workaround presented in that issue is to use the `ngForm` directive and use that one to reset the form:

```
<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="save()" #myForm="ngForm">
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm; 

// ...

.subscribe(data => {
  this.myForm.resetForm();
}
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f6uywv?file=app/select-overview-example.ts)**

Comment: @AdamJungen Try now, I updated answer and also provided a demo, seems to work now when using `resetForm()` :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `close()` method on the `mat-select` API.

You can reference the `mat-stepper` by using `ViewChild`

More methods to try [here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api). Hope this helps!